# Angular Mat dialog issue with MicrosoftEdge browser

Tags: angular

I am migrating angular js to Angular 4 recently and have come across a strange issue of opening a dialog using MatDialog from '@angular/material' the implementation works perfect on chrome but issues on Edge/IE. Below is the implementation which causes issue.

```
public viewDocument()
{
 this.someService.getviewDocument(this.viewModel)
        .subscribe((data) => {
            if (data) {
                let dialogRefl = this.dialog.open(ViewDialogComponent);
                dialogRefl.componentInstance.viewData = this.viewDataModel;
                dialogRefl.componentInstance.setDataOnInit(data);
            }
    }); }
```

in the above code ViewDialogComponent is imported in the current component as 
import { ViewDialogComponent} from "./view-dialog.component"; what I observed while debugging is this.dialog is undefined and ViewDialogComponent as undfined
wondering what could be the reason for Edge/IE as on chrome its working as expected.

The method viewDocument() is being called from a hyper link click in a HTMl table column. Any pointer/help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to add the viewDialogComponent is being open from an existing Dialog componet.

Comment: If you want pass data to opened component, you can use data injection, please refer to official documentation https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component-

Comment: Thanks for the response well the issue is not to pass data but to open one dialog component from another, wondering if its an issue/limitation with IE/Edge to open when dialog component from another.

Comment: Looks like dialog.js of Angular is returning the inProgressDialog when trying to open a dialog from an opendialog.  MatDialog.prototype.open = function (componentOrTemplateRef, config) {
        var _this = this;
        var /** @type {?} */ inProgressDialog = this.openDialogs.find(function (dialog) { return dialog._isAnimating(); });
        // If there's a dialog that is in the process of being opened, return it instead.

Comment: You can open dialogs in whichever component you like via MatDialog service. There are also before/after open/close hooks. I dont actually get the problem you want to solve.

Comment: Well in my case from main view a dialog component(CompnentA) is opened with some data in a table and other  controls(textbox) and from this dialog component(ComponentA) I need to open other dialog component(ComponentB) without closing the ComponentA as the state has to be retained if user has entered some entries or checked some items. This is fine with chrome but IE and Edge has issue as on debugging I noticed that Edge is returning inProgress component i.e. ComponentA   let dialogRefl = this.dialog.open(ComponentB); here dialogRefl is assigned with ComponentA

Comment: Any occurence of shadowed variables? You can try to get a dialog ref via MatDialog#getDialogById function otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the info seems dialog.open doesnt support dialog on dialog.   Ref: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/698 . Appreciate if there is some reference as per your comment "You can try to get a dialog ref via MatDialog#getDialogById function otherwise."

Comment: Sure, here it is https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialog Btw it is possible to open dialogs from dialogs, I'm doing this in my projects and it works perfectly. The issue you linked is two years old and has no connection to current state of ng material

Comment: VagrantA opening Dialog on Dialog I was able to do on chrome browser the issue I am facing is with IE/Edge browser. Seems this is limitation with MS broswers.

Comment: I was able to open multiple dialogs on edge with no problems

Comment: let dialogRefl = this.dialog.open(ViewDialogComponent); well when I tried to open the same on edge I observed dialogRefl was refering the instance of ViewParentDialogComponent expected was ViewDialogComponent  there unable to access method of  dialogRefl.componentInstance.setDataOnInit(data);

Comment: You can use service for passing info. Thats what they're needed for.

Comment: Passing info is secondary first of all  unable to open the dialog from Dialog in IE.

Comment: Trying a differnt apporach to poen in new window.                                                                            
 let uri= 'api/v1/cfos/2005408328802_171212.1?
 Type=OrdCon&format=PDF&client=ABC'
  this.windowRef.nativeWindow.open(urlIe, '_blank');                Is there a sample to sanitize the raw pdf/html content in new browser window as at present it displays raw data.